# PHP - insert date into url

Tags: php, date, url

With this code I connect API with my project.
In `$sCurloptUrl` is my API url and from it I retrieve some data and put it in json format. I managed to retrieve everything except `time_from` and `time_to`. My url need to look like this: `http://localhost/Something/json.php?json_id=get_measurements&measuringStation_id=551&matter_id=2&data_type=4&time_from=16.5.2018&time_to=18.5.2018`  How to get time_from and time_to?

```
case 'get_measurements':

        $nMeasuringStationID= $_GET['measuringStation_id'];
        $nMatterID = $_GET['matter_id'];
        $nDataType = $_GET['data_type'];
        $sTimeFrom = $_GET['time_from'];
        $sTimeTo = $_GET['time_to'];

        $sCurloptUrl = 'http://iszz.azo.hr/iskzl/rs/podatak/export/json?measuringStation='.$nMeasuringStationID.'&polutant='.$nMatterID.'&dataType='.$nDataType.'&timeFrom='.$sTimeFrom.'&timeTo='.$sTimeTo.'';

        $headers = [
            'Content-Type: application/json',
        ];
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_HTTPGET => true,
            CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
            CURLOPT_URL => $sCurloptUrl
        ));
        $oResponse = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        $oResponse = json_decode($oResponse, true);

        //var_dump($oResponse);

        foreach ($oResponse as $Measurements) 
        {
            $oMeasurement = new Measurement( $Measurements['Data']['value'], $Measurements['Data']['measuring_unit'], $Measurements['Data']['time']);
            array_push($oJson, $Measurements);
        }   
    break;
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question though

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: How to get time_from and time_to with this code

Comment: What are those two fields called in your form?

Answer (score 0):

You have  time_from  in your url but you are adding it using  timeFrom and the same with timeTo and time_to 
so this will get your values:

```
    $sTimeFrom = $_GET['timeFrom'];
    $sTimeTo = $_GET['timeTo'];
```